# Why isn't my modified JavaScript showing up in the debugger?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have started my web application as website. I am calling JavaScript in it. Problem is in the script: the first time through, the script is working while debugging, but if I make any modification to the script and then try to debug it, control is moved to old lines and not new lines. I tried to rebuild, but still get the same result.

What may be the reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clear browser cache. Perhaps that's why it keeps old version of js.

Answer (score 1):

Performing a hard refresh ([CTRL] + [F5]) should reload the javascript too without having to clear the cache